# Digital Signature with XLSX and XAdES-T using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to sign XLSX file in office 2016 and add timestamp server, I used apache poi's code but it doesn't seem to work, every signing result returns XAdES-EPES. The result I expect is XAdES-T.
Here is the source code for apache poi with timestamp server signing:

https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/poi-ooxml/src/test/java/org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/dsig/TestSignatureInfo.java

```
void testSignEnvelopingDocument() throws Exception {
    String testFile = "hello-world-unsigned.xlsx";
    File sigCopy = testdata.getFile(testFile);
    UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream bos = new UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream(50000);

    final String execTimestr;


    try (OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(copy(sigCopy), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE)) {

        initKeyPair();
        final X509CRL crl = generateCrl(x509, keyPair.getPrivate());

        // setup
        SignatureConfig signatureConfig = new SignatureConfig();
        signatureConfig.setKey(keyPair.getPrivate());

        /*
         * We need at least 2 certificates for the XAdES-C complete certificate
         * refs construction.
         */
        List<X509Certificate> certificateChain = new ArrayList<>();
        certificateChain.add(x509);
        certificateChain.add(x509);
        signatureConfig.setSigningCertificateChain(certificateChain);

        signatureConfig.addSignatureFacet(new OOXMLSignatureFacet());
        signatureConfig.addSignatureFacet(new EnvelopedSignatureFacet());
        signatureConfig.addSignatureFacet(new KeyInfoSignatureFacet());
        signatureConfig.addSignatureFacet(new XAdESSignatureFacet());
        signatureConfig.addSignatureFacet(new XAdESXLSignatureFacet());

        // check for internet, no error means it works
        boolean mockTsp = (getAccessError("http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161", true, 10000) != null);

        // http://timestamping.edelweb.fr/service/tsp
        // http://tsa.belgium.be/connect
        // http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode
        // http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161
        // http://services.globaltrustfinder.com/adss/tsa
        signatureConfig.setTspUrl("http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161");
        signatureConfig.setTspRequestPolicy(null); // comodoca request fails, if default policy is set ...
        signatureConfig.setTspOldProtocol(false);

        signatureConfig.setXadesDigestAlgo(HashAlgorithm.sha512);
        signatureConfig.setXadesRole("Xades Reviewer");
        signatureConfig.setSignatureDescription("test xades signature");

        execTimestr = signatureConfig.formatExecutionTime();

        //set proxy info if any
        String proxy = System.getProperty("http_proxy");
        if (proxy != null && proxy.trim().length() > 0) {
            signatureConfig.setProxyUrl(proxy);
        }

        if (mockTsp) {
            TimeStampService tspService = (signatureInfo, data, revocationData) -> {
                revocationData.addCRL(crl);
                return "time-stamp-token".getBytes(LocaleUtil.CHARSET_1252);
            };
            signatureConfig.setTspService(tspService);
        } else {
            TimeStampServiceValidator tspValidator = (validateChain, revocationData) -> {
                for (X509Certificate certificate : validateChain) {
                    LOG.atDebug().log("certificate: {}", certificate.getSubjectX500Principal());
                    LOG.atDebug().log("validity: {} - {}", certificate.getNotBefore(), certificate.getNotAfter());
                }
            };
            signatureConfig.setTspValidator(tspValidator);
            signatureConfig.setTspOldProtocol(signatureConfig.getTspUrl().contains("edelweb"));
        }

        final RevocationData revocationData = new RevocationData();
        revocationData.addCRL(crl);
        OCSPResp ocspResp = createOcspResp(x509, x509, x509, keyPair.getPrivate(), cal.getTimeInMillis());
        revocationData.addOCSP(ocspResp.getEncoded());

        RevocationDataService revocationDataService = revocationChain -> revocationData;
        signatureConfig.setRevocationDataService(revocationDataService);

        // operate
        SignatureInfo si = new SignatureInfo();
        si.setOpcPackage(pkg);
        si.setSignatureConfig(signatureConfig);
        try {
            si.confirmSignature();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // only allow a ConnectException because of timeout, we see this in Jenkins from time to time...
            if (e.getCause() == null) {
                throw e;
            }
            if ((e.getCause() instanceof ConnectException) || (e.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException)) {
                assumeFalse(e.getCause().getMessage().contains("timed out"),
                    "Only allowing ConnectException with 'timed out' as message here, but had: " + e);
            } else if (e.getCause() instanceof IOException) {
                assumeFalse(e.getCause().getMessage().contains("Error contacting TSP server"),
                    "Only allowing IOException with 'Error contacting TSP server' as message here, but had: " + e);
            } else if (e.getCause() instanceof RuntimeException) {
                assumeFalse(e.getCause().getMessage().contains("This site is cur"),
                    "Only allowing RuntimeException with 'This site is cur' as message here, but had: " + e);
            }
            throw e;
        }
}
```

Comment: I can try to help you - for contact see my profile. If successful, you can post the solution here.

Comment: Hi @kiwiwings, I have reached out to you via email, hoping to hear from you.

Comment: As a reference, I add the [bugzilla entry](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65623) which will contain the fix soon. for users of POI 5.0.0, you can copy the XAdESXLSignatureFacet source and provide it in your user packages. The corresponding test case is "createXAdES_T_65623" in [TestSignatureInfo](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/poi-ooxml/src/test/java/org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/dsig/TestSignatureInfo.java?view=markup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The problem was **solved** with the enthusiastic and professional help of **[kiwiwings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2066598/kiwiwings)**
- If anyone has the same problem as me, you can follow kwiwing's instructions in the comment with the 2 links he described:

> As a reference, I add the **[bugzilla entry](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65623)** which will contain the fix soon. for users of POI 5.0.0, you can copy the XAdESXLSignatureFacet source and provide it in your user packages. The corresponding test case is "createXAdES_T_65623" in **[TestSignatureInfo](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/poi-ooxml/src/test/java/org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/dsig/TestSignatureInfo.java?view=markup)**